# web.config redirect to another domain on 404 error

Tags: azure, redirect, web-config, http-status-code-404, azure-web-app-service

We are migrating our old site to a new one (wordpress hosted on Azure) but for some reasons we need to maintain the old one one online. Suppose the site are:
new site www.site.com
old site www.oldsite.com
This is what we need:
if a user enter www.site.com/somepath and this doesn't exist, it must be redirected to www.oldsite.com/somepath.

Is it possible by setting url rewrites in web.config or by redirecting 404 error to the old domain?
Thank you in advance,
Marco

Comment: This document: http://zainrizvi.io/2016/04/07/block-default-azure-websites-domain/ might help to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hi! Thank for your suggestion, I just know that post and I use the solution for another website. But in this case I don't have to redirect anything but only URL that doesn't exist (404 error) so how do I write the rule???

Answer (score 0):

From your information, I'd assume you are using WordPress template (**not** WordPress on Linux) from Azure Marketplace (in which during the WordPress web provisioning, you are asked to chose whether Azure MySQL or MySQL in App option). You can download IIS Manager extension and remotely connect to your site then start writing your rule. You can also download the web.config file (via FTP and make it up yourself). Here is the reference of web.config https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32229.azure-create-an-url-rewrite-azure-web-app.aspx

The below is sample rule

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="404redirection">
    <match filterByTags="None" serverVariable="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^404" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" type="Pattern" pattern="^http://newwebsite.net/somepath(.*)">
      </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" value="http://oldwebsite.net/somepath(.*)" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
 </rewrite>
```

Note that this is the sample rule based on the web server variable with HTTP response (404). If you WordPress uses some custom query strings or so on, the rule is supposed to be more complicated than this one.

Comment: Hi Thuan Ng, thank you very much, I will try it! Just one question: is it possible to have somepath dynamic so it is valid for each 404 url not found?

Comment: @mtallon what do you mean? Do you need to remove somepath? If so just use (.*) like this http://yoursite.net/(.*). As long as the host is matched and the http response status code is 404, the rule is triggered

Comment: I mean this: user enter newwebsite.net/aaa and if path /aaa is not found on newwebsite.net then user must be redirected to oldwebsite.com/aaa; if user enter newwebsite.net/bbb and path /bbb is not found on newwebsite.net then user must be redirected to oldwebsite/bbb and so on. I hope is more clear now